# What is the effective way to replace all occurrences of a character with every character in the alphabet?

Tags: c++, string, loops

What is the effective way to replace all occurrences of a character with every character in the alphabet in `std::string`?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void some_func() {
string s = "example *trin*";
string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
// replace all '*' to 'letter of alphabet'
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    //replace letter * with a letter in string which is moved +1 each loop
    replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '*', letters.at(i));

    i++;
    cout << s;

}
```

how can i get this to work?

Comment: Is checking the output needed"

Comment: As your tag says a loop (or two) would be the correct way to do this. You should post the code you have written and state why it's not working as you want. Then you will get some more focussed help.

Comment: I have posted some code but don't know how to go about my issue

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're asking for? If you have the string `"extra example"` what string (or strings) do you want to get?

Comment: Having a really hard time deciphering what you are trying to communicate by `but what if i wanted to replace that character with every single letter in the alphabet and get all permutations of this`.

Comment: just changed the question a little so its easier to understand

Comment: @user19277023 are you asking how to do a `for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i)` loop?

Comment: that seems to be what im looking for yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have a function:

- receiving the string you want to operate on, and the character you want to replace, and
- returning a list with the new strings, once the replacement has been done;
- for every letter in the alphabet, you could check if it is in the input string and, in that case, create a copy of the input string, do the replacement using `std::replace`, and add it to the return list.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/cbzePf98K)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // replace
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> replace(const std::string& s, const char c) {
    std::string_view alphabet{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    std::vector<std::string> ret{};
    for (const char l : alphabet) {
        if (s.find(c) != std::string::npos) {
            std::string t{s};
            std::ranges::replace(t, c, l);
            ret.emplace_back(std::move(t));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::string s{"occurrences"};
    fmt::print("Replace '{}': {}\n", 'c', replace(s, 'c'));
    fmt::print("Replace '{}': {}\n", 'z', replace(s, 'z'));
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Replace 'c': ["oaaurrenaes", "obburrenbes", "oddurrendes"...]
//   Replace 'z': []
```

---

Edit: update on your comment below.

> however if I wanted to replace 1 character at a time for example in
> occurrences there are multiple "C" if i only wanted to replace 1 of
> them then run all outcomes of that then move onto the next "C" and
> replace all of them and so on, how could that be done?

In that case, you'd need to iterate over your input string, doing the replacement to one char at a time, and adding each of those new strings to the return list.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/abcsYPszE)

```cpp
    for (const char l : alphabet) {
        if (s.find(c) != std::string::npos) {
            for (size_t i{0}; i < s.size(); ++i) {
                if (s[i] == c) {
                    std::string t{s};
                    t[i] = l;
                    ret.emplace_back(std::move(t));
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Outputs:
//
//   Replace 'c': ["oacurrences", "ocaurrences", "occurrenaes"...]
//   Replace 'z': []
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply and solution, however if I wanted to replace 1 character at a time for example in occurrences there are multiple "C" if i only wanted to replace 1 of them then run all outcomes of that then move onto the next "C" and replace all of them and so on, how could that be done?

Comment: Updated my answer to consider your comment.